How to create a web application with express with registration
I'm trying to create a server with express that allows me to log in and register, and when I log in I can chat with connected users, I'm having some problems, any advice on how to do it?
I've done various tests, but I really can't, I need some useful advice, thanks in advance

How can we POSSIBLY advise you, when you haven't shown us a single thing you've done?  What do you have, and what does it not do?

this is a project I did a few years ago, I hope it can help you.
SERVER:
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');  // Modulo per leggere e scrivere file

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

// Percorso del file users.json per salvare gli utenti
const USERS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'users.json');

// Funzione per leggere gli utenti dal file
const loadUsers = () => {
    if (fs.existsSync(USERS_FILE)) {
        const usersData = fs.readFileSync(USERS_FILE);
        return JSON.parse(usersData);
    }
    return [];
};

// Funzione per salvare gli utenti nel file
const saveUsers = (users) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(USERS_FILE, JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
};

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Serve la directory statica (dove c'è index.html)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'www')));

// Carichiamo gli utenti dal file all'avvio del server
let users = loadUsers();

// Endpoint per registrarsi
app.post('/api/register', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log('Richiesta di registrazione ricevuta:', { username, password });

    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Username e password sono obbligatori' });
    }

    const userExists = users.some(user => user.username === username);
    if (userExists) {
        console.log('Registrazione fallita: Username già esistente');
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Username già esistente' });
    }

    const newUser = { username, password };
    users.push(newUser);
    saveUsers(users);  // Salviamo gli utenti nel file JSON
    console.log('Registrazione completata per:', username);
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Registrazione completata' });
});

// Endpoint per il login
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log('Richiesta di login ricevuta:', { username, password });

    const user = users.find(user => user.username === username && user.password === password);
    
    if (!user) {
        console.log('Login fallito: credenziali non valide');
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Credenziali non valide' });
    }
    
    console.log('Login avvenuto con successo per:', username);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login avvenuto con successo', username });
});

// Gestione della chat con Socket.io
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Un utente si è connesso');

    // Associa l'username al socket
    socket.on('setUsername', (username) => {
        socket.username = username;
        console.log(`L'utente ${username} si è connesso alla chat`);
    });

    // Gestione dei messaggi in chat
    socket.on('chatMessage', (msg) => {
        const message = `${socket.username}: ${msg}`;
        console.log('Messaggio ricevuto:', message);
        io.emit('chatMessage', message);  // Invia il messaggio a tutti i client connessi
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`L'utente ${socket.username} si è disconnesso`);
    });
});

// Avvia il server
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server avviato sulla porta 3000');
});

Client:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login e Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Sezione Autenticazione -->
    <div id="auth-section">
        <h1>Registrazione</h1>
        <form id="registerForm">
            <input type="text" id="registerUsername" placeholder="Username" required><br>
            <input type="password" id="registerPassword" placeholder="Password" required><br>
            <button type="submit">Registrati</button>
        </form>

        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form id="loginForm">
            <input type="text" id="loginUsername" placeholder="Username" required><br>
            <input type="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" required><br>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Sezione Chat -->
    <div id="chat-section" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Chat Room</h1>
        <div id="messages" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;"></div>
        <form id="messageForm">
            <input id="messageInput" type="text" placeholder="Scrivi un messaggio..." required>
            <button type="submit">Invia</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const authSection = document.getElementById('auth-section');
        const chatSection = document.getElementById('chat-section');
        const socket = io();
        let loggedInUser = null;

        // Funzione per registrarsi
        document.getElementById('registerForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const username = document.getElementById('registerUsername').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('registerPassword').value;

            fetch('/api/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                alert(data.message || data.error);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Errore:', error));
        });

        // Funzione per fare login
        document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const username = document.getElementById('loginUsername').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('loginPassword').value;

            fetch('/api/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.message) {
                    // Se il login ha successo, memorizza l'username e mostra la chat
                    loggedInUser = username;
                    socket.emit('setUsername', username);  // Invia l'username al server
                    authSection.style.display = 'none';
                    chatSection.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Errore nella richiesta di login:', error));
        });

        // Funzione per gestire i messaggi della chat
        document.getElementById('messageForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInput');
            const message = messageInput.value;

            // Invia il messaggio al server tramite Socket.io
            socket.emit('chatMessage', message);

            // Svuota il campo di input dopo l'invio
            messageInput.value = '';
        });

        // Ricevi e mostra i nuovi messaggi della chat
        socket.on('chatMessage', (msg) => {
            const messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
            messageDiv.textContent = msg;
            document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(messageDiv);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

